# Issues typing a react component that takes dynamic props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I’m trying to create a React component which takes another component type, and returns it with some specific props injected.

I have narrowed it down to a simpler example. It should be usable like this:

```js
function MyInput({ name }) {
  return <input name={name} />
}

<Foo component={MyInput} specificProp />
```

This is the code of my Foo component:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface ComponentProps {
  name?: string;
}

interface FooSpecificProps<C extends React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>> {
  component: C;
  specificProp: string;
}

type FooProps<C extends React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>> = Omit<
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<C>,
  keyof FooSpecificProps<C>
> &
  FooSpecificProps<C>;

export default function Foo<C extends React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>>({
  component: Component,
  specificProp,
  ...props
}: FooProps<C>): React.ReactElement {
  return <Component {...props} name={specificProp} />;
}
```

I’m getting this error:

```js
Foo.tsx:23:11 - error TS2322: Type 'Pick<FooProps<C>, Exclude<Exclude<keyof PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<C>>, "component" | "specificProp">, "component" | "specificProp">> & { name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<C, PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps>>'.
  Type 'Pick<FooProps<C>, Exclude<Exclude<keyof PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<C>>, "component" | "specificProp">, "component" | "specificProp">> & { name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<C, PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps>>'.

23   return <Component {...props} name={specificProp} />;
             ~~~~~~~~~
```

The implementation code is really simple, but how do I fix the typings?

Comment: Isn't this the definition of Higher Order Components? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: No, but it is similar. HOCs create a new component type for the given component. My example renders a component type that is passed through props.